# How to sleep less than a second in linux bash

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script which simply needs to sleep for less than a second.
However 'sleep' only accepts seconds as input.

Is there any command to sleep less than 1000 ms?

Answer (score 4):

`sleep` from GNU Core Utilities *does* accept decimal numbers. From [sleep(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sleep.1.html):

> Pause for NUMBER seconds.  SUFFIX may be `s` for seconds (the
> default), `m` for minutes, `h` for hours or `d` for days.  **NUMBER
> need not be an integer.**  Given two or more arguments, pause for the
> amount of time specified by the sum of their values.

I also tested BusyBox version of `sleep` and confirmed that it also supports decimal numbers. This should clear any issues with even Alpine Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest workaround I could find is using bash's read builtin, which accepts milliseconds:

```
read -t 0.5
```

or with non bash scripts, for example fish:

```
bash -c 'read -t 0.5'
```

Comment: Beware that 'read -t' times out after the specified time and returns an error value (142).
It is actually a timeout function for reading user input, hence the value > 0